# Как связаны знаки с сайтами?

Tags: обсуждение, знаки

В уведомлениях на SO увидел сообщение о новом знаке с metaRuSO:

> You've earned the "Бродяга" badge (Задал вопрос, за который не голосовали, на который не отвечали, не комментировали и мало просматривали за неделю) for "Множественные копии при проверке".

Обратил внимание на смесь языков: шаблон фразы взят английский, но название и описание знака - русские. Тема само собой тоже русская, но тут уж без вариантов :)

Поэтому возник вопрос, с какой же целью это было сделано. Явно не из соображений локализации - тогда было бы логично брать шаблон фразы с того же сайта, откуда знак:

> Вы заработали знак «Бродяга» (Задал вопрос, за который не голосовали, на который не отвечали, не комментировали и мало просматривали за неделю) за «Множественные копии при проверке».

Тогда остаётся вариант, что изначально задумывалось, что знаки могут иметь разное название и описание на разных сайтах сети. Но зачем? Либо же просто комплекты знаков или условия их вручения могут различаться между сайтами.

Собственно сам вопрос: насколько велики возможности по конфигурированию знаков на сайте? Ясно, что можно менять название и описание, но это неинтересно. Что ещё можно?

- Можно ли выставлять другие числовые лимиты для получения знаков?
- Можно ли отключить часть знаков?
- А наоборот, добавить своих?
- Что-то ещё?

Comment: ну лимиты очевидно можно менять, успешно применялось, когда сайт был в бете

Comment: @Grundy, это у привилегий были другие лимиты. А вот со знаками - что-то ни одного не припомню.